# Can the paste() function produce numeric values?

Tags: r

I dynamically generate 5 variables each containing a random value:

```
> i = 1
> 
> while(i <= 5)
 {
   assign(paste("x", i, sep = ""), rnorm(1))
   i = i + 1       
 }
> x1
[1] 0.3853609
> x2
[1] 1.626055
> x3
[1] -1.043699
> x4
[1] 0.3449921
> x5
[1] -0.9768416
```

Is there any function in R that will allow me to dynamically display the value of each of the variables. What I mean is a function like:

```
> paste("x", 1, sep = "")
[1] "x1"
```

that would not produce a character string, but that would show the value of the variable `x1`. In this way, I could create a loop to display all the values.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I guess you are looking for `get`, but you should be advised that your whole approach goes horribly against the concepts of the R language. I guarantee you that there is a much better way to achieve your final goal. You probably need `x <- rnorm(5); x[1]; x[2]; x[3]; x[4]; x[5]`.

Comment: @Roland This example is an oversimplified version of what I am attempting to do. Thank you very much. 'get' works perfectly. I know loops are not very popular in R but what I need is to create 5 different variables.

Comment: I agree with @SimonO101, you should use more appropriate object types, like a list.

Comment: @SavedByJESUS Loops are very popular in R. However, you should use them only when needed (not the case in your example). Especially a `while` loop you will almost never need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not make them in a single list object. Lists are great to work with because each element can hold objects of any type and can be of different sizes, so you don't need to guarantee the return value of your function produces an identically sized output. In this simple cases, I would use `replicate` to draw 5 independent random normal deviates:

```
 n <- 5
 x <- replicate( n , rnorm(1) , simplify = FALSE )
[[1]]
[1] 1.820713

[[2]]
[1] -0.2326797

[[3]]
[1] -0.7698173

[[4]]
[1] -0.3954702

[[5]]
[1] -0.5585051
```

You can access each element through subsetting with `[[`, e.g. to get the second result:

```
x[[2]]
[1] -0.2326797
```

Which I guarantee is much easier that working with 5 separate variables.

Comment: There is no need for `replicate` here. `as.list(rnorm(5))` works just fine if you really need a list.

Comment: @Roland thanks. I thought `replicate` was *better* (?!) to use when the function being evaluated invovled `RNG`. I admit the docs are not very clear on why I should ever use `replicate`. I guess its just in the cases where you do not have a vectorised function like `rnorm`?

Comment: @imonO101 Compare `set.seed(42); rnorm(5)` with `set.seed(42); replicate(5,rnorm(1))` and then benchmark.

Comment: The difference is more important when you do something like `replicate(10, mean(runif(5)))`